# Conda environments in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, environment

I have two Anaconda environments I created, say A and B, plus the base env.
I have created environments A and B specific to what I do with them (different libraries).

Now I installed VScode. When I open VScode and set first the correct interpreter (A or B) in the lower part and run some python programs specific to A and B, the program does not run and error appears.

```
D:\Anaconda\envs\practica-mldl\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\practica-mldl\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\practica-mldl\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\practica-mldl\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Do\Python\ML practice\iris\own-knn.py", line 15, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\practica-mldl\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\practica-mldl\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "D:\Anaconda\envs\practica-mldl\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.

PS D:\Do\Python\ML practice\iris> conda activate practica-mldl

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

But when I open VScode through anaconda prompt by first activating the environment and opening VScode by typing **code** and running some programs, the program runs.

So from what I understand, simply changing the interpreter in VScode is not the same as opening VScode by activating first the environment. I thought by just changing the interpreter in VScode will work.

Is there a setup in VScode where I do not have to open VScode by activating the environments first so I can run python programs specific to that environment?

Thanks a lot!

Edit 1. Added error

Comment: Odd, I haven't had that problem. You say "the program does not run and error appears", what is the error message presented?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I edited the question and added one of the errors. Thanks!

Comment: @user587266 -According to the VS Code display information you provided, the problem seems to be in the module "numpy". Please try to reinstall the module "numpy" in the required python environment.